# Is it a bad practice to export all different widgets inside a single widget then import these widgets by importing this single file wherever we need?

Tags: flutter, performance, performance-testing, overhead

If I create a file like `widgets.dart` and put the exportation of all my widgets inside that like below:

```
export 'custom_app_bar.dart';
export 'content_header.dart';
export 'vertical_icon_button.dart';
```

Then import this file wherever I needed one of these widget inside another file like below:

```
import './widgets/widgets.dart';
```

Is it a bad practice and would have overhead process/memory issues?

I am also thinking about put more codes in the same file, for example define 3 different `MobileSizeHomeScreen() , TabletSizeHomeScreen(), DesktopSizeHomeScreen()` classes/widgets inside one file like `home_screen.dart` instead of creating 3 different mobile, tablet, desktop files, but don't know doing such a things would cause performance or maintenance issues while the project gets larger and more complexed or not?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that isn't a bad practice. However, Dart presents us with `part` and `part of` to do that kind of stuff. You can read more about Dart effective usage [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage).

Suppose all of those four files are within the same directory.

In the above's case, `./widget/widgets.dart` would have this line (above the class declaration):

```
part 'custom_app_bar.dart';
part 'content_header.dart';
part 'vertical_icon_button.dart';
```

and in each of those three, they will have this line that indicates, they are part of the `./widget/widgets.dart`:

```
part of 'widgets.dart';
```

Then, when you need one of the widgets, you only need to import `widgets.dart`

I see some of the other Dart developers also use the `export` stuff, so it is a matter of preference. Personally, I would prefer what Dart recommends, which is using `part` and `part of`.

Comment: So you say it's only a matter of preference not performance?

Comment: I would assume it won't affect performance that much and I don't which one is better in a term of performance. However, following what is mentioned by Dart is the best practice.